# std::cout overhead if closed (STDIN_FILENO)

Tags: c++, cout, overhead

I have background process (daemon on unix system) that have `std::cout` for debug on the source file at some places. I run this daemon on silence mode or NO silence mode. On `silence mode` after start of process I execute this bit of code:

```
std::cout.rdbuf(0);
close(STDIN_FILENO);
close(STDOUT_FILENO);
close(STDERR_FILENO);
```

And as you understand `std::cout` is still present on the code and run.

On `NON silence mode` there is a big overhead, while `cout` to the screen is very expensive and slow IO operation.

**The question:** 
What overhead of the code on `silence mode`? Is there some "drag" for my program due to `std::cout` present, but with closed `STDOUT_FILENO`? (time to time it try to print up to 1 kilobite of info)

and how big this overhead?

Comment: Wouldn't be better to use another `streambuf` object for that? Let's say `clog` constructed to use `cout` when you need such data and to _nothing_ (just discard inputs) when you're running in silent mode? Point (IMO) isn't if overhead is big or not (just measure) but if it's clear or not.

Comment: I does not know, I use this solution because it's easy to print something on the screen if deamon on debug (non silence mode), and easy switch off all `cout` at the work environment. But I suspect that this solution have some overhead. Seems you suggest something like my, if `cout` with closed STDOUT_FILENO does not have overhead (for example if it's check on the start of the function is STDOUT_FILENO open or not)

Comment: you may simply blindly replace all `std::cout` with `yourapp::clog` and it'll work. You just have to initialize `clog` according to options. Overhead...well I think (but what I think is not a measure) half of will come with strings you build/data you prepare (and it won't be avoided if you simply drop output to null).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Using a streambuf which just discards the output is the classical solution, but it will result in all of the conversions taking place, which can be non-negligible.

Answer (score 2):

It obviously has some overhead.  But not much; the first thing in every `<<` is to test that the stream status is good.  And it *shouldn't* be if the corresponding physical device is closed.  At the very least, it will go bad after the first flush (due to the buffer becoming full).  Alternatively, you could call `std::cout.rdbuf( nullptr )`, which should make it go bad immediately.

The traditional solution has been to create a no-op streambuf.  This has the advantage that the stream doesn't go bad: reads just always see end of file, and output always works.  It has the disadvantage that because the stream state is good, you actually format all of the output: `std::cout << someDouble` will do all the work of converting the double into a sequence of characters.  If the stream state is bad (as it will be with a `nullptr` as the stream buffer), the `<<` operators return before having tried to convert anything.

Comment: thanks for you answer. And maybe there are some other good alternatives for my situation?